# Binding keys to buttons on a Ps3 gamepad controller

Tags: games, minecraft, gamepad, ps3

I have both a dual shock 3 and a knock off wired ps3 controller. I'm running 14.04 trusty tahr on a presario cq57 from compaq, no windows installed.
I have a AMD C-50 Processor × 2, 1.6 GiB of memory.

I have been looking all over the internet for how to make it work with something like tf2 and/or minecraft pc version. There is plenty of documentation about Xbox drivers and all sorts of programs which can bind the buttons to keyboard keys but as I have searched and tried different things none of it makes sense to me.

I am new to ubuntu so I need a step by step process of how to get a program to bind various keys to various buttons on a ps3 controller. Simple files which I can open up with software center would be nice or instructions on how to do it from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

TF2 should have native controller support, at least it does on Windows. Try configure your controller in Steams BigPicture mode, that makes controllers work in most modern games or at least SDL2 based ones.

As for games that can't be made to work that way, try QtSixA.

Comment: how would one acquire this program?